# In Python/Django, when I click on a textfield box (like a login) it takes me to a certain page

Tags: python, django, authentication, field

So yeah, when I click on any form, it takes me back to a certain page, specifically my account login page. It was working before, and it actually works fine in IE, but not in Firefox or Chrome. Here's the code for the actual account/login.py file, but there are 100s of files in the program, so it would be impractical for me to list them all here.

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from account import models as amod
from . import templater
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate


def process_request(request):

    form = User_Auth_Form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = User_Auth_Form(request.POST)


        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(username = form.cleaned_data['username'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])

            if user.is_staff == True:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/manager/dashboard')


            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("homepage/index")

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/homepage/index')

    tvars = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return templater.render_to_response(request, 'login.html', tvars)


class User_Auth_Form(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()


    def clean(self):
        user = authenticate(username = self.cleaned_data['username'], password = self.cleaned_data['password'])
        if user == None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Bad password or username")

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: You need to give some details. How can we help without seeing any code?

Answer (score 0):

Please post the/a template page, and perhaps the/a url(s) file.

P.S. A simplification of your `request.method/POST` code is:

REPLACE

```
form = User_Auth_Form()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = User_Auth_Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
```

WITH

```
form = User_Auth_Form(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
```